# Why is the Python Socket connected to ser2net returneing garbled characters?

Tags: python, sockets, serial-port, decode

I am using ser2net on raspberry pi to make a tcp/serial bridge. When I connect to the raspberry pi using python socket tcp protocol, all I recieve is something like this:

```
b'\x08\x00\xff\xf1\x04\x1d\x08\x00\xff\xf1\x03\xe9\x08\x00\xff\xf1\x04\x03\x08\x00\xff\xf1\x04;\x08\x00\xff\xf1\x04\r\x08\x00\xff\xf1\x03\xad\x08\x00\xff\xf1\x03\xa2\x08\x00\xff\xf1\x03\xdf\x08\x00\xff\xf1\x03\xe5\x08\x00\xff\xf1\x03\xb1\x08\x00\xff\xf1\x03\xde\x08\x00\xff\xf1\x048\x08\x00\xff\xf1\x04D\x08\x00\xff\xf1\x03\xe9\x08\x00\xff\xf1\x03\xd0\x08\x00\xff\xf1\x03\xf8\x08\x00\xff\xf1\x03\xd9\x08\x00\xff\xf1\x03\x8d\x08\x00\xff\xf1\x03\x9d\x08\x00\xff\xf1\x03\xf7\x08\x00\xff\xf1\x04\x1a\x08\x00\xff\xf1\x03\xe7\x08\x00\xff\xf1\x03\xfa\x08\x00\xff\xf1\x044\x08\x00\xff\xf1\x04\x19\x08\x00\xff\xf1\x03\xb4\x08\x00\xff\xf1\x03\x97\x08\x00\xff\xf1\x03\xd3\x08\x00\xff\xf1\x03\xda\x08\x00\xff\xf1\x03\xa1\x08\x00\...'
```

When I decoding the raw data the error with utf-8 or ASCII, it will raise an "UnicodeDecodeError" error.

Settings including baud rates, parity, the number of stop bits, the number of data bits are configured correctly according to the serial reference.

Comment: Perhaps these are telnet options negotiation codes? Obviously some non-character protocol is running and you'll have to figure out what it is.

Comment: In the reference, it says COMMAND: get:  Get the set thresholds “_OK” followed by + threshold then –threshold in binary fashion (16 bit signed integer) Low byte then high byte, followed by “_OK”. what  is binary fashion (16 bit signed integer)?

Comment: the python`struct` module can help you send and receive 16-bit integers. low byte followed by high byte is also known as little endian: use "<" as the first character of `struct.pack()` and `struct.unpack()`.

Comment: @piet.t could you post your code for python socket here? im currently trying the same in Java